# Undeclared identifer error in prepareForSegue : using Storyboards in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to build a 2 scene application using Storyboards in iOS6.
I am taking the users name via text input in the first scene and passing it using a push segue to the second scene; where it is displayed in a label.

The first scene's UIViewController is called ViewController and the second scenes UIViewcontroller is DrawViewController.

I have imported the the DrawViewController.h in my ViewController.m file where I have defined the prepareForSegue as below:

```
  -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ColorPickerControllerSegue"]){

        DrawViewController *dvc =[segue destinationViewController];
        dvc.userName= self.userName;
    }
    }
```

Here userName is a NSString defined in DrawViewController.
I am getting "use of undeclared identifer:DrawViewController".
I am quite new to iOS programming, so is there something I am missing here?

I have set the second view controller's custom class to DrawViewController.

Comment: #include "DrawViewController.h" in the beginning of the implementation?

Comment: yes! I am failing to understand where I am going wrong!

Comment: From what you're showing an error isn't obvious.

Comment: I deleted the existing view controller.h and .m files and added them again and followed the same process.It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the existing DrawViewController.h and DrawViewController.m files and then creating and adding them back to the the project.
It seemed to do the trick.